# Is it possible to save an oxyplot into a list?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to save some oxyplots into a list where I can then later generate a pdf or png file for printing to a printer. Is this something that is possible?

I have two classes; one is a plotUsercontrol and the other being a Baseplot.

Also, I did not implement the oxyplots feature of the app so I'm not fully aware of the differences between PlotModel and PlotView.

In my snippet PlotUserControl. I have the following function which I created to grab all the plots from the BasePlot. I declared it as void because I was not sure what type to declare the Data type for the list and function as.

```
        public void getPlots()
        {
            foreach(var plot in plots)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine(plot.getImage());
            }
        }
```

Bellow is just a fucntion from my baseplot that  gets the PlotModel. Also I wasn't sure whether to return the plotModel or the plotView.

```
    public PlotModel getImage()
        {
            return this.plotModel;
        }
```

I hope this make sense. New to c#.

Comment: Is it that bad of a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to safe your images or the plots into a list? If you want to save plots into a list, that's already done (`plots`).

However if you want to save images into a list that's a bit different but very easy. I suggest you take a look at `List<T>`. I can supply you with method that will do all the work but it is so easy that i think you can manage to set up the list on your own.

Here is a quick rundown tho: `List<T>` will create a list which allows you to save objects of the datatype `T` inside of it. `T` is a so-called generic type which means you can hand it every data type that can be instantiated. 
Hint: `T` would be `PlotModel` in your example.

If you need any more help, feel free to contact me but I think you can manage creating said list on your own.

[This is the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) to the Microsoft Docs of `List<T>`, but imo they are not the best docs for beginners. Just look for some tutorials on Google.

---

Another tip tho, rename your functions. In C# first letters of words in method names are uppercase (e.g: `GetPlots()`, `GetImage()`). This is just a common naming style although you can stick to lowercase.

Comment: Thanks for the information. My goal is to take take the plots, turn them into images and save them in a file. I am however still confused a little on what to set the data type to store the plots as images.

Comment: I'd recommend asking a new question and referring to this question. An idea would be to use a Stream or rather a FileStream but i don't know what your plots support